# ConfigurationManager.GetSection always gives object with default values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, configsection

Here is the ConfigurationSection class

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace CampusWebStore.Config
{
    public class PoolerConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("PoolId", IsRequired = true)]
        public string PoolId { get; set; }
        [ConfigurationProperty("Host", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Host { get; set; }
        [ConfigurationProperty("Port", IsRequired = true)]
        public int Port { get; set; }
        [ConfigurationProperty("Enabled", IsRequired = true)]
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The web.config section definition

```
<section name="PoolerConfig" type="CampusWebStore.Config.PoolerConfig, CampusWebStore"/>
```

The actual section

```
<PoolerConfig
    PoolId="asdf-asdf-asdf-asdf"
    Host="localhost"
    Port="5000"
    Enabled="true"
  />
```

And then the line that loads it (in Global.asax.cs)

```
PoolerConfig poolerConfig = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("PoolerConfig") as PoolerConfig;
```

It seems that no matter what I do, all the properties in my PoolerConfig are default values (null strings, 0 ints, etc). Research indicates this should be easy as pie, but to no avail I cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `get/set` backers for configuration properties.  You must access the base class to manipulate the properties.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx for an example.

Change:

```
 [ConfigurationProperty("PoolId", IsRequired = true)]
 public string PoolId { get; set; }
```

To:

```
 [ConfigurationProperty("PoolId", IsRequired = true)]
 public string PoolId 
 {
    get { return (string)this["PoolID"]; }
    set { this["PoolID"] = value; }
 }
```

Comment: This was definitely the answer. I must have been thrown off by a previous developer. He did something slightly different. He had defined his ConfigurationSection class with the normal get/set backers, but was loading it in the web.config as an xml file using the configSource attribute. Thanks for the help.